# How to convert logic to pointer logic

Tags: c, pointers

How to covert logic to pointer logic, so below i have it the way I understand to code, but I need this to be using pointer like it says in the TODO, please advise, TY :)

This is what is said in the TODO that is not helping me understand, (Hint: to avoid doing double pointer arithmatic, save a char* pointer
    //      to the active chunk[?] in the outer loop but before the inner loop.
    //      Then the inner loop is only concerned with a single array of
    //      characters rather than an array of strings.)

Loop over each string in the array of
    //      message chunks (strings) and print it. Do not print the first
    //      character in each string since it is only used to store the order of
    //      the chunks. (Hint: use pointer arithmetic to skip a character.)

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//INCLUDES
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

//macros: constants
#define CHUNK_LENGTH (20+1)  //each chunk has twenty characters, we add 1 so
                           //there is space for the null terminator.
#define NUMBER_OF_CHUNKS 4 //the message is spread across 4 chunks.
#define DECRYPTION_SHIFT 5 //this is the ASCII table shift used for decryption.

//forward declarations
void sort_chunks();
void decrypt_chunks();
void display_chunks();

char chunks[NUMBER_OF_CHUNKS][CHUNK_LENGTH];

int main() {
    //copy message into memory.
    strcpy(chunks[0], "2i1%fsi%fs%jstwrtzx%");
    strcpy(chunks[1], "1'H%nx%vznwp~1%kqf|j");
    strcpy(chunks[2], "4R3%Wnyhmnj%%%%%%%%%");
    strcpy(chunks[3], "3xzhhjxx3'%2%Ijssnx%");

    //the format of a chunk is a single number indicating its order in overall
    //message followed by twenty encrypted characters.


    //reorder chunks in message by sorting them based on the first digital
    //they contain. looking above, one can see they are currently in the order
    //2, 1, 4, 3 but should be ordered 1, 2, 3, 4.
    sort_chunks();

    //shift the characters in the message to produce the original characters.
    decrypt_chunks();

    //display the decrypted message.
    display_chunks();


    return 0; 
}

//given two strings, swaps their contents in memory.
void swap_strings(char* x, char* y) {
    //create a temporary holding place for the data so we don't lose it.
    char temp[CHUNK_LENGTH];

    strcpy(temp, x);
    strcpy(x, y);
    strcpy(y, temp);
}    

//sorts the strings the global chunks variable by the first character they contain.
void sort_chunks() {
    //TODO: Implement sort_chunks(). Using your favorite sorting algorithm (we
    //      suggest selection sort), sort the array containing the message chunks.
    //      Sort based on the first character in the chunk - it will always be a
    //      number. We provide a swap_strings function that you may use. Example
    //      usage: swap_strings(chunks[0], chunks[1]) will swap the contents of
    //      the first and second string.

   int i, j;
   int lowest;
   for (i = 0; i < NUM_OF_CHUNKS - 1; i++)
   {
       lowest = i;
       for (j = i + 1; j < NUM_OF_CHUNKS; j++)
       {
           if (chunks[j][0] < chunks[lowest][0])
               lowest = j;
       }
       swap_strings(chunks[i], chunks[lowest]);
   }
}

//for each string in the global chunks variable, shifts the characters in it by
//DECRYPTION_SHIFT.
void decrypt_chunks() {
    //TODO: Implement decrypt_chunks(). Loop over each string in the array
    //      and shift the characters in it by subtracting DECRYPTION_SHIFT value
    //      from them. Use pointer arithmetic to access individual characters but
    //      array access to the strings. Remember that C-style strings have a null
    //      terminator at the end. Do not apply the shift to the terminator.
    //      (Hint: to avoid doing double pointer arithmetic, save a char* pointer
    //      to the active chunk[?] in the outer loop but before the inner loop.
    //      Then the inner loop is only concerned with a single array of
    //      characters rather than an array of strings.)

    int row, col;
   for (row = 0; row < NUM_OF_CHUNKS; row++)
   {
       for (col = 0; col < CHUNK_LENGTH - 1; col++)
       {
           if (chunks[row][col] != '\0')
               chunks[row][col] -= DECRYPTION_SHIFT;
       }
   }

}


//displays the strings in the global chunks variable
void display_chunks() {
    //TODO: Implement display_chunks(). Loop over each string in the array of
    //      message chunks (strings) and print it. Do not print the first
    //      character in each string since it is only used to store the order of
    //      the chunks. (Hint: use pointer arithmetic to skip a character.)
   int row, col;
   for (row = 0; row < NUM_OF_CHUNKS; row++)
   {
       for (col = 1; col < CHUNK_LENGTH - 1; col++)
       {
           if (chunks[row][col] == '\0')
           {
               printf("\n");
               return;
           }
           printf("%c", chunks[row][col]);
       }
   }
   printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: Well, considering your functions take no parameters, it is somewhat impossible with the state of your question to help. That said, you can read the tea leaves enough to know that between the inner and outer loop you will want a `char *p = whatever[row];` so you can then `printf ("%s\n", p + 1);` (avoiding the first character). [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You appear to have done a good job on 1 & 2, e.g. When asking about homework you should **(1)** Make a good faith attempt to solve the problem yourself first (include your code in your question). **(2)** Ask about specific problems with your existing implementation (including any errors you are receiveing). **(3)** Admit that the question is homework. **(4)** Be aware of your school policy. **(5)** Never use code you don't understand. See: [**How do I ask and answer homework questions?**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: i would send the whole thing but the comment is character limited

Comment: You can edit your question and include the whole thing. (or at least a minimal compilable example that demonstrates your current working code) Right now we are guessing about what the global chunks variable is, whether the strings it contains or points to are *nul-terminated*, etc.. That said, I think if you read through my first comment, it will point you in the direction you need to go.

Comment: In fact, in `display_chunks`, you can simply add `char *p = global_chunk_var[row];` and then `printf ("%s\n", p + 1);` and remove the entire inner loop to accomplish the print. Also *never* `printf("\n");` (or any single character), the proper tool for outputting a single character is `putchar ('\n');`

Comment: its homework and I want to know how to make it use pointers instead, i did the TODO part but not using the pointers idea, I would like advise how to tackle that, I will give the whole code right now with edit.

Comment: Read edited comment just above your last.

Comment: char *p = chunks[row];
    printf("%s, p+1"); that prints nothing though

Comment: Where the hell do you think the closing `"` goes? `:)`

Comment: Take the compiler's warning serious.

Answer (score 0):

Let's make this instructive. Let's use a simple preprocessor define `WPOINTERS` to allow your code to be compiled to use pointer or use the two loops in your original code:

```
//displays the strings in the global chunks variable
void display_chunks() {
    //TODO: Implement display_chunks(). Loop over each string in the array of
    //      message chunks (strings) and print it. Do not print the first
    //      character in each string since it is only used to store the order of
    //      the chunks. (Hint: use pointer arithmetic to skip a character.)
    int row;
    for (row = 0; row < NUMBER_OF_CHUNKS; row++)
    {
#ifdef WPOINTERS
        char *p = chunks[row];
        printf ("%s", p + 1);
#else
        int col;
        for (col = 1; col < CHUNK_LENGTH - 1; col++)
        {
            if (chunks[row][col] == '\0')
            {
                putchar ('\n');
                return;
            }
            putchar (chunks[row][col]);
        }
#endif
    }
    putchar ('\n');
}
```

If you specify `-DWPOINTERS` on the command line during compile, the following code is executed:

```
#ifdef WPOINTERS
        char *p = chunks[row];
        printf ("%s", p + 1);
```

otherwise, your original code is executed:

```
#else
        int col;
        for (col = 1; col < CHUNK_LENGTH - 1; col++)
        {
            if (chunks[row][col] == '\0')
            {
                putchar ('\n');
                return;
            }
            putchar (chunks[row][col]);
        }
```

In both cases you obtain:

```
$ ./bin/prnwptrsnew
"C is quirky, flawed, and an enormous success." - Dennis M. Ritchie
```

Example compile strings would be:

```
$ gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=gnu11 -Ofast -DWPOINTERS -o bin/prnwptrsnew prnwptrs.c
```

or for your original code, just omit `-DWPOINTERS`:

```
$ gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=gnu11 -Ofast -o bin/prnwptrsnew prnwptrs.c
```

If you are using `cl.exe`, the with/without `-DWPOINTERS` works the same.

Comment: using NetBeans IDE

Comment: Is that on Linux or Windoze? You don't have to include the preprocessor directives. Just remove the `#ifdef WPOINTERS` and delete `#else` to `#endif`...  (and for learning C -- get rid of the IDE, and use the command line so you can learn what compiler options you need and what they do -- then you can tell an IDE what you want rather than hoping it has the right options set...)

Comment: Seriously, for learning and simple programs (even containing multiple source files), you are better off using the command line. IDE's hide that from you and you miss out on a fundamental part of how compiling and linking actually take place.

Comment: NetBeans uses `gcc` (either cgywin or MinGW), so the compiler options and defines are the same, see [C/C++ Application Learning Trail](https://netbeans.org/kb/trails/cnd.html) generally, and [Configuring NetBeans IDE for C/C++/Fortran](https://netbeans.org/community/releases/80/cpp-setup-instructions.html) specifically.